# How can I select or change the theme on pudb (Python Debugger)?

Tags: python, debugging, pudb

I've been using pudb to debug python code, it's pretty straight forward and into the terminal.
But I don't like the colors it has at all.

It is something like the image below.

I found in the folder inside

```
.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pudb
```

a file name **themes.py** but even if a try to change it there nothing happens

[image: Classic Theme]

Answer (score 9):

There is a config menu `Ctrl + p` and there you can select a theme.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the pudb config file at `~/.config/pudb/pudb.cfg` and set `theme = dark vim`. For example, here is the snippet from my `pudb.cfg` :

```
.
.
sidebar_width = 0.5
stack_weight = 1
stringifier = default
theme = dark vim
variables_weight = 1
wrap_variables = Tru
.
.
```

Available themes(Jan 2023) taken from [here](https://github.com/inducer/pudb/blob/main/pudb/theme.py) are :

```py
THEMES = [
    "classic",
    "vim",
    "dark vim",
    "midnight",
    "solarized",
    "agr-256",
    "monokai",
    "monokai-256",
    "mono",
]
```